# AngularJS file input onchange event to controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<input onchange="angular.element(this).scope().filesChanged(this)" fileInput="controlFormCtrl.formData.episodeFile">
```

The file selected, will be passed to the scope, and will be accessible inside my controller in this way:

```
  var thisScope = this;
  var rootScope = $root;
  var ctrlScope = $scope;
  ctrlScope.filesChanged = function(elm) {
    thisScope.file = elm.files[0];
  }
```

elm.files has the following data:

```
lastModified: 1485109128000
lastModifiedDate: Sun Jan 22 2017 19:18:48 GMT+0100 (CET)
name:"border-image.png"
size:1353
type:"image/png"
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__: File
```

However the `thisScope.file` is not being set.

What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: ctrlScope.file instead of thisScope.file would work, however I am using `controllerAs` as i have multiple controllers nested under eachother.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to run `ctrlScope.$apply();` to let angular know that `thisScope` has changed.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Good shout, since having to  use `onchange` instead of `ng-change` (which isn't supported for this type of input), Angular won't have ran a $digest cycle.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah it halfly worked, the variable is still empty or at list it looks like, the problem is that the datatype of `elm.files` is `FileList` which is not a simple array.

Comment: Maybe that is because you need to `$apply()` after the file is loaded since it is an async event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `ctrlScope.$apply();` to let angular know that `thisScope` has changed, however, this should only been run after the `FileReader` has loaded the file.

I recommend using the `ngf-select` directive to handle file uploads.

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload